# iPhone Chart: How can we zoom in in Core Plot ? (example code: AAPLot)

Tags: iphone, sdk, charts

iPhone Chart: How can we zoom in  in Core Plot ? (example code: AAPLot)

I am now using Core Plot to draw a Chart by example Code AAPLot

```
CPTGraphHostingView *graphHost;
IBOutlet UIScrollView *_scrollview;
IBOutlet UIView *zoom_view;    
APYahooDataPuller *datapuller;
CPTXYGraph *graph;
```

How to let the View zoom in and zoom out?